# Is it possible to set a minimum viewport height?

Tags: jquery, html, css, viewport

I have a page that has a general layout like so:

```css
header {height: 10vh; width:100%; background-color:black;}
#wrapper {height:70vh; width: 100%; background-color: white; }
footer {height:20vh; width: 100%; background-color: grey;}
```

```html
<header>
</header>
<div id="wrapper">
image 
</div>
<footer>
</footer>
```

and this looks fine on mobile devices until the screen orientation is changed to horizontal. Is it possible to set a miniumu  viewport height? I'm using

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

and tried this

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, min-height=500">
```

with no luck. Is there a CSS or jQuery method for this?

Comment: The problem is I need a min-height the width is fine its just the height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a media-query for a `max-height`, maybe also combined with `orientation: landscape` and put seperate height settings for these elements in there (i.e. the necessary minimum heights), like

```
@media screen and (max-height: 600px) {
  header {height: 100px;}
  #wrapper {height:700px; }
  footer {height:200px;}
}
```